# Low internal storage, message memory full and sluggishness problems on Samsung Galaxy Y Duos Lite

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, link2sd, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

I currently fixed that error by uninstalling all internal memory programs and re-installing them (In other words, formatting their data cache). I also found that you can solve this problem by using Link2SD Pro (which also moves the app's data files). I am leaving this thread open so that anyone can answer it with a better solution in the future.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Y Duos Lite (GT-S6102) phone rooted and Link2SD. I am always getting the error that my internal memory is always full, and after many factory resets, I installed Link2SD. I linked all the apps that can be linked and after finding that linking takes some space in internal memory, I app2sd all the apps that would and the rest of the user apps except Play Store, which I converted to a user app and I have on my ext2 partition. I ran the inbuilt cleaner on Android Assistant.

Recently it is giving the error Message Memory Full. I have 9 mb free of 170 mb.This time it won't go at all no matter what I do. I need to receive my SMSs on my phone. It is also very sluggish.

I appreciate any help.

Thanking you in advance,

Sanoo

Answer (score 2):

I use a backup tool ([SMSBackupRestore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore)) to save old message on my sd card. Very nice because you can read the backup file to find your old messages.

I followed the same scheme as yours (I own a Samsung Galaxy Y Pro - GT-B5510). The only problem I still have now is the low ram. Apps are becoming more and more greedy and even the simplest apps need 20Mb RAM and that's too much with all the "Google Services" taking up to 50Mb. So now, I'm trying to find a way to overcome the lag caused by the low RAM.

From what I read on forums, the problem of low space comes from the apps mostly. But messages take space too (I had some problem too) and lag was coming from the messaging app that doesn't bear so many messages. So backup was the only solution for me.

Comment: Great answer, but SMSBackupRestore doesn't solve the problem as SMS doesn't take a lot of space on my phone. Even the most basic if apps (The inbuilt bloatware and LBE Privacy Guard) is enough to fill the phone's storage (170mb).